# ERROR Cannot start nuxt: Context is not availablet

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to run  the Nuxt3 app but when I'm trying to run *npm run dev* then this error showing in my console:  ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  Context is not available

Anyone have face the same type of issue and how to fix that.

Comment: Hi, what did you do and tried to debug that one? Some effort is expected here. It will also make the debugging faster.

Comment: Actually a package is missing, then I just run this command: npm install context

Comment: Hm, I highly doubt a package is missing here. Did it worked at the end?

Comment: Yes it's worked, but right now I'm facing this issue, when I'm trying to run *npm run build*

This new error comes out: TypeError: C:\xampp\htdocs\stockV2\admin\.nuxt\client.js: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined

Can you help it out.

Comment: Facing the same issue with nuxt@v3.0.0-rc.7

Comment: Same issue when trying to run "Yarn generate"

Comment: For anybody facing the same issue here, you're welcome to create a new question with a [repro].

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but the problem was that I was trying to use Nuxt/Vue specific functionality in a `.ts` file.
I was abstracting some of the lengthier functions and `computed` objects into a composition file, specifically `import { useNuxtApp } from '#imports'` and `const { $store } = useNuxtApp()`. The `.ts` file has no Nuxt context so these imports and functions just won't work there!

Might you be experiencing something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, when i try generated app for production "npm run generate".

Most likely its a version issue, update nuxt to "3.0.0-rc.8"

https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/6583